# In scala compilation, how to enable "no tail recursion option"

Tags: scala, scalac, scala-maven-plugin

According to this document:

https://www.scala-lang.org/old/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/tools/scalac.html

I'm supposed to use "-g:notc", so I add it into my scala-maven-plugin configuration:

```
      <args>
        <arg>-target:jvm-${java.version}</arg>
        <arg>-unchecked</arg>
        <arg>-deprecation</arg>
        <arg>-feature</arg>
        <arg>-g:vars</arg>
      </args>
```

When I compile this project using maven install, I got this error:

> 'notc' is not a valid choice for '-g'

Is this option removed? What should I use instead?

Comment: Just curious. Why would you want to turn that off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was renamed. From the `man scalac` output (version 2.12.2):

```
-g:{none,source,line,vars,notailcalls}
```